# Postage Stamp Puzzle

Tags: python, recursion

I was given a set of problems by my instructor to get us thinking about recursion. In one of them, we are given a value (the cost of postage) and a list of available denominations of stamps. The exercise involves writing a recursive function that returns a minimum length list of stamps whose total is equal to the value sum of postage.

Is the correct way to solve this just to have the a program that compares every single possibility and return the one with the smallest length? If that's the case I'm not exactly sure how to write a program for it, much less one that utilizes recursion as I am new to both python and programming in general. Based on the hints the instructor provided I came up with something like this:

```
stampList=[1,4,7]
postage=10

def pickStamps(postage):
    if postage==0: #base case 1
        return ""
    if postage<0: #base case 2
        return none
    else:
        x=postage
        for i in range(len(stampList)-1):
        x=x-stampList[i]
        return pickStamps(x)
```

I was attempting to have python start with the value of postage and subtract each denomination in combination to get to zero,but I'm not sure how to make each possibility into a list. It was suggested in the problem that it might be wise to write another function that takes a parameter that is a list of lists and returns the index of the minimum length element in that list, but I'm not sure how to implement that. Can someone either show me how to write such a code or explain the best way to approach such a problem? Thanks!

Comment: Is this for an algorithms class? Are you asked to do dynamic programming? A greedy algorithm won't always give you the right answer

Comment: Here is a fun link to learn about dynamic programming and memoization http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Recursion/DynamicProgramming.html

Answer (score 1):

```
def ways(wallet, stamp_values, postage):
    amount = sum(wallet)
    if amount == postage:
        return [wallet]
    elif amount > postage:
        return []
    else:
        next_stamp = wallet[-1] if wallet else max(stamp_values)
        new_stamps = stamp_values[stamp_values.index(next_stamp):]
        gen = (ways(wallet + [c], new_stamps, postage=postage) for c in new_stamps)
        return sum(gen, [])
```

Test drive:

```
>>> combos = ways([], stamp_values=(7,4,1), postage=10)
>>> combos
[[7, 1, 1, 1],
 [4, 4, 1, 1],
 [4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>> min(combos, key=len)
[7, 1, 1, 1]
```

Note the solution is actually non-unique in your example, i.e. 7,1,1,1 and 4,4,1,1 are both the same length.

Let's imagine we have a new stamp of value 3, we should expect to see a unique solution then (7 + 3 == 10 with two stamps).

```
>>> ways([], stamp_values=(7,4,3,1), postage=10)
[[7, 3],
 [7, 1, 1, 1],
 [4, 4, 1, 1],
 [4, 3, 3],
 [4, 3, 1, 1, 1],
 [4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [3, 3, 3, 1],
 [3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seemed to work fine until I tested it for 50. It gave me 11,11,11,11,1,1,1,1,1,1 instead of 40,7,1,1,1. Do get the same response?

Comment: It works correctly for me using `ways([], stamp_values=(40,7,4,1), postage=50)`.  Note that my algorithm expects `stamp_values` to be sorted high to low.  It's easy to remove the restriction if you want to, I will leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Ah I hadn't noticed that restriction before, thank you. Also as a side note, I've not yet seen if and else statements without a : and indentation afterwards, could you pleas explain how they work in your code? Thanks!

Comment: That's called a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).  
`x = a if b else c` is a python one-liner for `if b: x = a else: x = c`

Comment: Thanks again! If I could bother you one last time, then the line reads next_stamp is equal to the rightmost value if wallet has a value and is not empty if not the next stamp is equal to the maximum value stamp. Also the restriction you mentioned is due to the new_stamps line, because we are checking the index of the list. The way to remove the restriction would be to change that line, right?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a function which already works:

```
def pick_stamps(postage):
    '''Returns list of stamps needed to cover postage'''
```

Given you have this function, you can use it to implement your version:

```
def my_pick_stamps(postage):
    if postage == 0:
        return []
    else:
        stamp = max(stamp for stamp in stamps
                    if stamp <= postage)
        return [stamp] + pick_stamps(postage - stamp)
```

Of course, once you've implemented your version you can use that instead and replace `pick_stamps` in your implementation with `my_pick_stamps`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Could you please explain how the two programs would work in tandem? I'm not too good at reading code, but it seems as though your code could work by itself if I changed the last pick_stamps to my_pick_stamps.

Comment: @88jerry88 exactly, that's the point with recursion. You assume you have a function which works, then use it to solve a smaller problem, which turns out to be the whole problem.